# Simple oscillator, but no sound with web audio API on IOS

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Here is a super simple example that I am trying to run on an iphone in chrome. Other web audio API examples like this one http://alxgbsn.co.uk/wavepad/ work, but not mine :(

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <script>
    var audioContext, osc
    audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
    osc = audioContext.createOscillator()

    osc.connect(audioContext.destination)
    if (osc.noteOn) osc.start = osc.noteOn
    osc.start(0)
    osc.frequency.value = 440
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Any idea what's wrong?

**EDIT**

To summarize the answer :

1. start the audio in response to user interaction
2. check that mute switch is off

Answer (score 12, accepted):

iOS will only let you start playing sound with the Web Audio API as a result of a user action.

Try putting that code inside of some kind of event handler.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('play'),
  audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext),
  osc = audioContext.createOscillator();

osc.connect(audioContext.destination);
if (osc.noteOn) osc.start = osc.noteOn
osc.frequency.value = 440;

play.addEventListener('click', function() {
  osc.start(0);
}, false);
```

Comment: Now got it working in chrome, but not in Safari (IOS 7). Any idea?

Comment: $10 says your mute switch is on. For whatever reason, Safari won't play sound when the mute switch is engaged, but Chrome will. Other than that, Chrome uses the same engine as Safari to render your page (minus the Nitro JS optimizations), so there's no other reason that your code should work in one but not the other. I just tried it via JSBin, and both worked for me when the mute switch was off.

Comment: Same for me. After two hours of diving into the color full world of unlocking ios web audio – finally the mute switch.

Comment: @KevinEnnis you are my hero!